# How would you print out the values exceeding the vector and replace them with NA in R?

Tags: r, vector, insert

I'm supposed to make a function where you can insert a value into a vector, but if you attempt to place the value outside of the vector it gives the following output
[image]

This is what I have done so far which works for values within the dimensions of the vector, but I cannot figure out how to get the output from the image above

```
a <- 1:10
insert <- function(x, where, what) {
 if(where<x+1) {
append(x,what,where - 1)}
  else{
print("Warning message")  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `where` exceeds the length of `x`, we can append `NA` to `x`. You can use `warning()` to display warning messages.

I've also changed your `if` statement to include `length()`, because we are comparing the length of `x` with your `where` argument.

```
insert <- function(x, where, what) {
  if (where < length(x) + 1) {
    append(x,what,where - 1)
  } else{
    warning(paste(where, "exceeds the dimension of the vector"))
    append(c(x, rep(NA, where - length(x) - 1)), what, where - 1)
  }
}

insert(a, 20, 0)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0
Warning message:
In insert(a, 20, 0) : 20 exceeds the dimension of the vector
```